# Usage of ことは/のは and 時々/ たり form

Tags: grammar, particle-こと

「ペットがいない方が楽だけど、時々犬が飼いたくなります」
"Having no pets is easier, but I sometimes want to have a dog"

My questions are:

1. can you use the たり form in this sentence to mean "I sometimes want a dog" (犬が飼いたくなったりします)?

2.can you use こと and のが after いない (ペットがいないことの方が楽です/ペットがいないの方が楽です)?

Comment: This sounds convoluted.  Why do you want to insert unnecessary words between a relative clause and the noun (which it is) that it modifies.

Comment: Because I (as a learner) want to gain a better understanding of the language and about what sounds unnatural and what might be unnecessary, or how to form a sentence differently and in other ways without it sounding weird. That's why I'm asking those kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is very common in Japanese recently. Young Japanese often use 'たり' to soften the tone of their phrases.
2. Native Japanese speakers never use such a phrase.

Comment: Thank you for answering! So if I want to use たり in this sentence, I can omit the 時々, right? Because I've been told that たり alone can already mean "sometimes" (犬が飼いたくなったりします= "I sometimes want to raise a dog")

Comment: This seems unnatural because '時々' means 'sometimes,' but 'たり' has nothing to do with tense. It means 'or something.'